# Not Getting Unique Id Generated By Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code which is for deleting a perticular post...
Here what i am doing is that when user click the delete button then the post should be deleted but insteed of that nothing is being deleting.Also when i put log to check whether i am getting the unique id generated by firebase database then it shows like this

'2020-04-16 10:00:41.328 29431-29431/com.example.zone D/sanyam: MBlog'

My firebase database Looks  Like this(I want to delete the that unique id)

````
MBlog
-M4iN100Ic5TiSjRRTtX
-M4iNkUGOCd7aKSqg09q
-M4mco3s-nEo0ohXYwIm
-M4xzHyoJjE0QY-5cKeZ
   ``` 

    //delete button
 ```      holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            mPostDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MBlog"); //child name must be same otherwise the
            //DatabaseReference newPost = mPostDatabase.getRef();
            mPostDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String uid = mPostDatabase.getKey();

                    Log.d("sanyam",uid);
                    mPostDatabase.child(uid).removeValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        });

  }```
````

Comment: you want to remove only value , or also the key . and please also add your firebase database screenshot / or just confirm that there is no parent about Mblog

Comment: There is no parent above Mblog

Comment: please do check my answer , if it is working do mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The dataSnapshot is still a list. To access the item, you need to loop over the result:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String uid = snapshot.getKey();
        Log.d("sanyam",uid);
        mPostDatabase.child(uid).removeValue();                 
   }
}
```

**But if you run this query all items will remove.**

If you want to remove one item you can do it like this:

```
 mPostDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MBlog").child(uid);
 mPostDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
          String uid = dataSnapshot.getKey();
          Log.d("sanyam",uid);
          mPostDatabase.removeValue();
      }

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all that value at once

```
mPostDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MBlog");
mPostDatabase.removeValue();
```

but if you want to delete particular node/ref

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            mPostDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MBlog"); //child name must be same otherwise the
            //DatabaseReference newPost = mPostDatabase.getRef();
            mPostDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String uid = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d("sanyam",uid);
                    if(uid.equal("M4mco3s-nEo0ohXYwIm")){//Here you can check UID
                        removeDataRef(dataSnapshot.getRef())
                       }

                     }
                        //mPostDatabase.child(uid).removeValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        });
```

And If you want to get callback of remove complete here is the listener

```
 public void removeDataRef(DatabaseReference ref){
ref.removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                //Here you can check the operation of remove completed or not
            }
        });
```

}